# integral conversions for signed char

Tags: c++, type-conversion

TCPL 3rd Edition, C.6.2.1 Integral Conversions gives the following example:

```
signed char c = 1023; // implementation defined
```

> Plausible results are 255 and -1 C.3.4

The -1 option is obtained *if* the target machine uses 2s complement.

What implementation of 'signedness' would result in 255?

Comment: you could try to ask Bjarne Stroustrup [his homepage]http://www.stroustrup.com/ [look it up on his university]http://www.cs.columbia.edu/people/directory/#Stroustrup [linkedin]https://www.linkedin.com/in/bjarnestroustrup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compiler could trivially replace your static initialiser with `= 255` in this case, on a whim.

But I'd just like to say that looking for an answer to this question is the wrong approach to programming C++. The book is teaching you about C++, not about specific computers. Code to standards and you won't have any problems.

Comment: While I agree with your general comment, I think it's a fair and interesting question, asking for a deeper understanding about the C++ standard and compliant implementations (as in, choosing another value "on a whim" will probably not be compliant, following gory C++ standard details). Possibly not a perfect fit for StackOverflow, though, given it's about practical programming questions.

Comment: This answer clarified that the result could actually be anything. I thought potentially there was something deeper going on, but this made it clear that the result could be arbitrary

Answer (score 0):

Honnestly I know no implementation that woult result in 255. It is theorically possible, but for a signed char to have a 255 value, the char type shall have at least 9 bits: 8 for the data value and one for the sign.

But as you are converting a value that cannot be represented into a signed type, the result is implementation dependant(*), so it could legitimately be MAX_CHAR for any integer value greater than it, which is 127. Or an implementation could choose to convert unacceptable values to 0.

In any way, it has nothing to do with what is the representation of negative values. Except that common implementations use 2's complement and simply keep the lowest order bits which ends in -1.

But what is true with common implementations is that:

```
char c = 1023;  // plausible values are -1 (default char is signed) or 255 (default unsigned)
```

---

(*) Refs:

From n4296 draft for C++14

> 4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral]
>   ...
>
> 3. If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type;
>      otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.